# How can I customize header in Drupal 7 (Bartik theme)?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm creating a site on Drupal 7. There are fields 'sitename' and 'site slogan' in theme settings but I need at least two more fields to show some information in header. How can I do that? (I'd like to keep Bartik, I know that choosing another theme is some kind of solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should just add some custom blocks in that region? (Structure>blocks>add new block)

If you think that you are going to customize a lot the Bartik theme, I'd suggest you to create a Bartik's subtheme to customize the default Bartik. To do so, please follow the guide: https://www.drupal.org/node/1114190

Comment: Thank you, custom block worked just fine, but there's some problem with Mozilla Firefox (in all other browsers header looks fine, but in Firefox my block moves for some reason so header becomes too big). Have you ever had such problem?

Comment: Sorry I haven't encounter this kind of problem. It seems very mysterious. What did you mean by "it moves"?

Comment: Happily, I found a solution. The thing is that I used full html format to code block content so Firefox understood css "font-size: larger" in its own way and displayed text inside block much larger than other browsers. That's why it looked fine in Chrome, Opera, Safari etc, but in Firefox it moved to the new line and header's height became bigger. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Ho right! You're welcome. I don't know if you know the principle of Stackoverflow but when you've got your answer to  your question, you can "check as right answer" the solution (the little V in the left of my answer). In that way, other people who have the same question as yours can immediately see which answer is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For adding new admin settings field in drupal you need to create a custom module to add extra fields (Editing core modules is not entertained)

You can write admin menu like below,

```
function MODULENAME_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/config/system/yourpath'] = array(
        'title' => 'Your menu name',
        'description' => 'Menu description',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('YOURFORMFUNCTION'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function YOURFORMFUNCTION($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['fieldname'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field title'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('fieldname', 'Default text'),
        '#description' => t("more description about field."),
        '#required' => TRUE, 
    );
    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Then you can display that by getting value using `variable_get('fieldname', 'Default text')`

Comment: @JSunny..i m new in drupal.. i m working on drupal 7. I have copy paste your code on my_module.module file..and on output it have a form and save configuration button..But after save configuration i m not able to see menu name which one i have entered..please help me.